# What is the height of a man walking away from a street light 12 ft high, if his shadow is moving twice as fast as he is?

Tags: calculus

The goal is to find h, the man's height. The height of the light post is given, 12ft. Also, we know that the change in position of the shadow is twice as much as the change in position as the man. From this, I got:

height (h) / 12 = Shadow Distance from Man (S) / Man's Dist. from light (M) + S

12s = h(M+S), so h= (12s) / (M+S)

This is where I was confused. I know I can derive with respect to time, with dh/dt = 0. However, there are three variables and we only know 1 of them: 2*dM/dt = dS/dt.

Comment: The last equation is wrong, because $\frac{dS}{dt}$ measures the relative speed at which the shadow moves away from the man, which is *not* the absolute speed at which the shadow moves. What you *do* know is $\frac{d(M+S)}{dt}=2 \frac{dM}{dt}$.

Answer (score 0):

The tip of the man's shadow has position $x+s=L$, so its rate of change with respect to time is: $\frac{d(x+s)}{dt}=\frac{dL}{dt}$. But it is given that this rate of change is twice that of the man, so we have the relationship: $\frac{d(x+s)}{dt}=\frac{dL}{dt}= 2\frac{dx}{dt}$, since his rate of change is $\frac{dx}{dt}$.

To find the man's height, note that his speed is constant, so we have $\frac{dx}{dt}=v$ for some constant $v$. So then his position is $x(t)=vt +c_0$, where $c_0$ is his starting point. I assume the man starts at $0$, i.e. at the lamp, though this isn't mentioned in the problem. Then we have $x(t)=vt$. Now $\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{ds}{dt}$ so $s(t)=x(t)+c=vt+c$ for some constant $c$. $c=0$, since if the man starts at $0$, at this time he casts no shadow as he is directly beneath the lamp, so we have $s(t)=x(t)$.By similar triangles: $\frac{12}{x+s}=\frac{h}{s}$, so $h=\frac{12s}{2s}=6$, so the man is $6$ feet tall.

Answer (score 0):

[image: ShadowSpeed]

Proportion in similar triangles:

$$ \frac{h}{12} = \frac{s}{s+m}= \frac{\dot s}{\dot s+\dot m} = \frac{\dot s/\dot m}{\dot s/\dot m +1 } = \frac{2}{2+1}= \frac{2}{3}\rightarrow h= 24/3 = 8^{\prime} $$

The ratio is constant, so numerator and denominator are differentiated with respect to time by the Quotient Rule.

Comment: How do you read the question to get $\dot s/\dot m = 2\,$? See my other comment under the OP.

Comment: By definition of speed of a moving object, its  rate of change of $m$ is measured from a fixed object like a light post. Shadow length $s$ is changing.

Comment: Precisely. But the distance to the fixed point is $m+s$, and $m$ is changing as well, so the speed at which the tip of the shadow moves is $\frac{d}{dt}(m+s) = \dot m + \dot s\,$. The problem states that that's twice $\dot m\,$, so $\dot s / \dot m = 1 \,$.

Comment: OP states that  *shadow length part* moves doubly fast as  the man.

Comment: Quoting: "*his shadow is moving twice as fast* ***as he is***". Obviously, the man must be moving as well, and the tip of his shadow moves at double his speed. How else do you read it?

Comment: That is why I marked the segment $s$..

Comment: Sorry, don't follow. I made my point into a separate answer.

Comment: P.S. On closer read, I guess this is what we understood differently. Your comment says: "*OP states that* ***shadow length part*** *moves doubly fast as the man*". But I don't read that into the question. What the OP actually said is: "*the change in position of the shadow is twice as much as the change in position as the man*". Confusing as it is, this appears to refer to "*position*" not "*length*". Since the shadow is defined by the *two* positions of its endpoints, and one of them is always the same as man's position, I assumed the question actually referred to the position of the tip.

Comment: @dxiv In your comments you said  $d(M+S)/dt = 2 dM/dt $ or, $ \dot m + \dot s = 2 \dot m $  or, $  \dot s = \dot m $. This is not what OP wants. OP wants  $  \dot s = 2 \dot m $

Comment: I find that unlikely, but in the end that's left to the OP to clarify. The distance "*from the foot of lamppost to the tip of shadow*" (as you wrote in another comment) is $m+s\,$, so its rate of change is $\dot m + \dot s\,$.

Comment: Right, this last one only was incorrect, Regrets and so deleted it. But all the rest stays.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the man starts walking from the base of the lamppost, where he has no shadow. Some time after that, the man is at distance $x$ from the lamppost. The tip of his shadow, having traveled twice as fast during the same time, will be at distance $2x$ from the lampost. By similarity of the obvious triangles, $\frac{2x}{12}=\frac{2x-x}{h}$ therefore $h=6$.

Answer (score 0):

Denote the heights of the lamppost and of the man by $h_l$ and $h_m$, and denote the distance of the man and of the tip of his shadow from the lamppost by $m$ and $s$. Then
$${s\over h_l}={s-m\over h_m}$$
and therefore
$$s={h_l\over h_l-h_m} m$$
at all times. The condition $\dot s=2\dot m$ leads to $h_m={\displaystyle{h_l\over2}}=6$ ft.